# SSRS reporting for data representing in table just once for particular row value

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I had sql result shown below...

```
ProjectNO.    Projectname      Client    Programmers
01              ave             zica       dee
01              ave             zica       law
01              ave             zica       amy
01              ave            rowan      dee
01              ave            rowan       law
01              ave             rowan      amy
```

Now how would I represent this into SSRS as

```
ProjectNO.    Projectname      Client    Programmers
  01              ave           zica       dee
                                rowan      law
                                           amy
```

or how can i achieve this ?

```
ProjectNO.    Projectname    Client1    Client2   Programmer1   Programmer2   Programmer3
  01             ave           zica       rowan      dee           law          amy
```

I was confused how to group them all according to Project name and Number.

---

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ my steps to Solution @@@@@@@@@@@@@

Hi All,

Anyways, I figured it out using Stuff function with For XML path I got the answer Just for one column field

with  Programmers in single cell (comma sepearted Prgrammers name)  and Clients which happened to appear in Single cell instead appeared in individual cell ...like below

```
ProjectNO.  Prjtname      Programmers          Client    
01             ave        dee, law, amy          zica        

01             ave        dee, law, amy          rowan
```

Any suggestion or examples  with  (Stuff + For XML path)  using individually with each(2 or more ) column... I had applied STuff+FOR XML path for both Programmers and Clients.

Comment: Remove the mysql tag,this is sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 groups ProjectNO.,Projectname and Client
Like on picture
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhhy3.png

here is a result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Supje.png

Comment: This is not that I expect, the programmers should not be repeated.. for particular projects.. but thanks

Comment: Then don't group on Client

Comment: then there will be a 1 to 1 relation between Client and the Programmers...which is more awefull

Comment: After using Hide Duplicate..  (note - neglect spacing)                                                         http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/329066e2-a029-4b4c-a31d-2a2090eba8e3/ssrs-how-display-multivalue-field-just-once?forum=sqlreportingservices